# Не могу прочесть код автора

Tags: kotlin, лямбда-выражение

Я пишу на kotlin довольно продолжительное время, но увидев код одного из репозиторий на github, я упал в ступор. Он везде применяет **Дженерики** и **Лямбда-выражения**, и еще куча разного сахара из Kotlin. **Может вы знаете** не плохую ссылку, кто даст понятие **как работает подобное**. Или хотя бы не большой пример привести.

```
sealed class Lce<out T> {

    abstract fun <R> map(f: (T) -> R): Lce<R>

    inline fun doOnData(f: (T) -> Unit) {
        if (this is Success) {
            f(data)
        }
    }

    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Lce<T>() {
        override fun <R> map(f: (T) -> R): Lce<R> = Success(f(data))
    }

    data class Error(val message: String) : Lce<Nothing>() {
        constructor(t: Throwable) : this(t.message ?: "")

        override fun <R> map(f: (Nothing) -> R): Lce<R> = this
    }

    object Loading : Lce<Nothing>() {
        override fun <R> map(f: (Nothing) -> R): Lce<R> = this
    }

    companion object {
        inline fun <T> exec(copy: (Lce<T>) -> Unit, f: () -> T) {
            copy(Lce.Loading)
            try {
                copy(Lce.Success(f()))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                copy(Lce.Error(e))
            }
        }
    }
}

fun <T> Lce<T>.orElse(defaultValue: T): T = (this as? Lce.Success)?.data ?: defaultValue
```

Comment: можно в документации смотреть: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/

Comment: Что именно Вам тут не понятно? Я код на котлине вижу впервые, поэтому вряд-ли смогу дать хороший ответ, но мне кажется что я его понимаю.

Comment: Это конструкция для получения текущего статуса какого-то процесса. `sealed class` является абстракцией ТОЛЬКО над тремя классами `Success`, `Error` и `Loading` - расширять его нельзя. Т.е. если что-то возвращает `Lce`, то, по факту, это будет один из трех заданных внутри него классов. В функции `orElse` проверяется текущий статус и, если он равен `Lce.Success`, то возвращает `data`, а при любом из двух других - `defaultValue`

Comment: Очень помогает посмотреть на код Kotlin декомплированный из байткода. Для этого в студии Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode, а затем Decompile. Становится понятно как работают эти лямбды и какие штуки лучше не использовать. На мой взгляд приведенный код это все же перебор :)